# Showing the centralizer of an element is the centralizer of that element's inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, and let $a$ belong to $G$. Prove that $C(a) = C (a^{-1})$ where

$$C(a) = \{x \in G | ax = xa\}.$$

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you need help with?

Comment: Am not able to prove it..need help with how to prove

Comment: I am a beginner. My questions may look bad and stupid, but honestly I don't know how to solve this. I don't know why my question gets down voted? How do I ask a question next time, if I don't know how to even attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\forall s \in C(a)$ we have that

$$
\begin{align}
sa &= as \\
a^{-1}(sa)a^{-1} &= a^{-1}(as)a^{-1} \\
(a^{-1}s)(aa^{-1}) &= (a^{-1}a)(sa^{-1}) \\
(a^{-1}s)(e) &= (e)(sa^{-1}) \\
a^{-1}s &= sa^{-1} \\
\end{align}
$$

thus $s \in C(a^{-1})$.